# Removing URL encoding from Active Record query

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm in over my head as always, but it's the only way I learn. Right now I am trying to query a column in a database for the current user and return the values. I'm using something like:

```
@tags = current_user.tags.select(:name).each { |p| p.name}
```

But it returns:

```
%5B%23%3CTag+name%3A+%22tag1%22%3E%2C+%23%3CTag+name%3A+%22tag2%22%3E%2C+%23%3CTag+name%3A+%22tag+test%22%3E%5D
```

From what I understand is that's Url Encoding. Is it possible to clean that up? I've tried using `.delete` or `.gsub` but I must be doing something wrong. Any insight? All my research on the site yields how to URL encode, but not URL decode.

Comment: Why are you using each? You should be using `map` or `collect`.

Comment: Okay, `collection` returns more of what I what, just the names themselves. However, they are still surrounded by url encoding characters. Without going into to much detail, for testing another aspect of the project I'm trying to add this info into a cookie. I was hoping I could have it formatted properly if I did it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For URI encoding/decoding you can take a look at [rubyonrails.org:URI::Escape](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/URI/Escape.html)

For displaying HTML in Rails views check out the raw() method [rubyonrails.org:ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html)

Comment: The problem is, it has to go into a cookie. Right now I have something like `@tags = current_user.tags.select(:name).collect { |p| p.name }` which is returning `["tag1", "tag2", "test tag"]`. It seems to be getting encoded when I embed it in the cookie using `cookies[:login] = { :value => "#{current_user.id}.#{@tags}", :expires => Time.now + 3600 }`. I tried using `URI` or `gsub` to decode it but all I get are errors or the commands get ignored. Needless to say, I don't think I know what I am doing.

Comment: The standard doesn't clearly say cookie values can/can't be URL encoded but most cookies are URL encoded. Have you tried creating a simple cookie first? Try creating a new cookie __cookies[:stuff] = "testing stuff"__ then grab the value from the cookie and toss it in an instance variable __@test = cookies[:stuff]__ and finally use a view to display it __<%= @test %>__. Returns "testing+stuff" if I look at the cookie using Firefox. However returning the value from the cookie returns a space instead of a "+" character. The cookie key/value pairs are not meant to look pretty via browser.

Comment: That's basically what I was wondering. I figured a cookie will always be formatted with URL encoding. It seems easier to have the other app decode the contents of the cookie. So what I have now is good enough. I'll check this answer because you guided me to a solution. Thank you so much!